# WordPress taxonomy for CPT goes to 404 page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages, custom-taxonomy

Within WordPress I have set up my Permalinks with a custom structure of `/resources/insights/%postname%/` with the category base as `resources/insights/category` which works exactly as intended.

I have a CPT called `clients` with the following code:

```
register_post_type('clients',
    array('labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Clients'),
        'singular_name' => __('Client')),
        'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail'),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'clients', 'with_front' => false),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-analytics'
    )
);
```

this also works as intended. However, I have set up a taxonomy for the `clients` but when I go to the taxonomy page it presents with a 404. This is my code for the taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy('client-categories', array('clients'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'clients/category', 'with_front' => false),
));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Amazing answer here:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/390275/239526  which might clear this up for you.